# How to query the custom fields using the params in postman

Tags: postman, commercetools

"custom": {
"type": {
"typeId": "type",
"id": "023c76a9-25ce-4937-987c-b1375be9f2bf"
},
"fields": {
"pending": "pending"
}
}

we have tried passing the query
custom(fields(pending= "pending"))
Can you please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to query the custom field on an order for example, the query could look something like this:
https://api.europe-west1.gcp.commercetools.com/yourProjectKey/orders?where=custom(fields(orderno%20%3D%20%22AA00004557%22))

query predicate:
custom(fields(orderno = "AA00004557"))

order example:

```
    {
      "type": "Order",
      "id": "af8381bb-d598-4fff-bfe6-33d7c6eab038",
      "version": 1,
      "country": "DE",
      "orderState": "Open",
      "syncInfo": [],
      "lineItems": [
      ],
      "custom": {
        "type": {
          "typeId": "type",
          "id": "e178b5b4-dede-42bd-9102-fcd5b992a9cf"
        },
        "fields": {
          "orderno": "AA00004557"
        }
      }
    }
```

If the custom field is from different type than text, enum, date, ltext, lenum you may need a different predicate. Same goes if the custom field is nested within the object, like on a product price.

You can try to query in impEx first, which makes the decoding and encoding a bit easier.
https://impex.europe-west1.gcp.commercetools.com/playground?endpoint=orders&method=read&query-where=custom(fields(orderno+%3D+%22AA00004557%22))&query-sort-order=asc

You can also have a look at the commercetools documentation for query predicates:
https://docs.commercetools.com/api/predicates/query

Comment: https://mc.us-central1.gcp.commercetools.com/bics-ecommerce/orders/80c2ca5b-9e23-4fcb-9ab4-a026b64ab9fb/custom-fields  This the url coming for the customfields for order. I have tried same in Impex it is working there but not working in postman